# Android isScreenOn Nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, wakelock, powermanager

i used this code to keep the screen on on Android 4.4.2.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```

The code does work, but after some time the app crashes (maybe one time in 24 hours)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.os.PowerManager.isScreenOn(PowerManager.java:739)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.&lt;init&gt;(ViewRootImpl.java:454)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:250)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3028)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3930)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there a solution or workarround for this?
Is this hardware/software related?

the only useful thread i found was:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43008

Answer (score 2):

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` should be called before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

The correct sequence should be

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: i do call it in this order

Answer (score 1):

In my case on emulator, I solved this problem by creating virtual device using Google Play image. There are 2 alternatives for every API level. Choose Google Play one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

> Java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
**setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

> xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true">
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

More info : [Keep the Screen On](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)